# Why my USB can't be mounted? bad superblock on /dev/sda

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount

I checked lshw

```
sudo lshw -C disk
  *-namespace               
       description: NVMe namespace
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
       size: 476GiB (512GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: guid=1365106e-6114-4a62-8424-b8aeb90e20cb logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
  *-disk
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: DataTraveler 3.0
       vendor: Kingston
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       serial: 0
       size: 57GiB (61GB)
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          size: 57GiB (61GB)
```

lsblk shows only

```
sda           8:0    1  57.6G  0 disk
```

I tried to mount

```
sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/mydrive
mount: /mnt/mydrive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

How to check bad option or bad superblock?

```
sudo file -sk /dev/sda
/dev/sda: data

Disk /dev/sda: 57.64 GiB, 61872793600 bytes, 120845300 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Are you sure your `sda` is a superfloppy (a filesystem on the entire device, without partitions)? What is the output of `sudo file -sk /dev/sda`? `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski added,take alook pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sda` represent the entire disk while I'm sure you want to mount an individual partition. `sudo fdisk -l` will show all of them.

Linux perfectly allows to use an entire disk as a partition but other operating systems including Microsoft Windows will not be able to use them.

Comment: added,please take a look.

Comment: This device does not seem to contain a valid partition table or any recognizable partition types. If it's brand new, please partition it e.g. using `gparted`.

Comment: That means I should format it?

Comment: Please use `sudo gparted`. It's the easiest method to partition disks under Linux. Remember Windows doesn't allow removable USB flash sticks to have more than a single partition. If it's a USB disk, then you can have as many partitions as you like. This looks like a USB stick, so please have a single partition if you intend to use it with Windows.